# validate all form elements at once using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

i'm validating a form but the validation goes a field by field and i want it to validate all fields at once on submit

here's the js code not inside document ready

```
function checkUser(){
var userlen = $("#user").val().length;
if(userlen<4){
    $("#user").css("background-color","#d2699b");
    return false;
}
else{
    $("#user").css("background-color","#0C9");
    return true;
}
}

function checkEmail(){
var email = $("#email").val();
if((email.length < 6) ||
 (email.indexOf('@',0) < 1) ||
 (email.lastIndexOf('@') != email.indexOf('@',0)) ||
 (email.lastIndexOf('@') > (email.length - 5)) ||
 (email.lastIndexOf('.') > (email.length - 3)) ||
 (email.lastIndexOf('.') < (email.length - 4)) ||
 (email.indexOf('..',0) > -1) ||
 (email.indexOf('@.',0) > -1) ||
 (email.indexOf('.@',0) > -1) ||
 (email.indexOf(',',0) > -1)){
     $("#email").css("background-color","#d2699b");
    return false;
}
else{
    $("#email").css("background-color","#0C9");
    return true;
}   
}

function checkPhone(){
var phone = $("#phone").val();
if(!$.isNumeric(phone)){
    $("#phone").css("background-color","#d2699b");
    return false;   
}
else{
    $("#phone").css("background-color","#0C9");
    return true;
}
}

function checkCountry(){
var country = $("#country").val();
if(country == 0){
    $("#country").css("background-color","#d2699b");
    return false;   
}
else{
    $("#country").css("background-color","#0C9");
    return true;    
}
}

function validate(){
if(!checkUser() || !checkEmail() || !checkPhone() || !checkCountry() ){
    return false;   
}
else{
    return true;
}
}
```

and the html code

```
<form method="post" action="data.php" onsubmit="return validate();">
<table width="40%" border="1">
<tr>
<td>user</td>
<td><input type="text" id="user" onblur="checkUser()" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>email</td>
<td><input type="text" id="email" onblur="checkEmail()" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>phone</td>
<td><input type="text" id="phone" onblur="checkPhone()" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>country</td>
<td><select id="country" onchange="checkCountry()">
<option value="0">choose</option>
<option value="egypt">egypt</option>
<option value="usa">usa</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" id="save" value="save" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

code in action : http://jsfiddle.net/JCtyJ/

Comment: y u no use validate.js. Please dont waste time reinventing the Wheel, steering, brake or whatever

http://validation.bassistance.de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, you could do it like that:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JCtyJ/1/)

```
function validate(){
    $.each($('form :input'),function(){
        $(this).blur().change();        
    });
    if(!checkUser() || !checkEmail() || !checkPhone() || !checkCountry() ){
        return false;   
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".vault_form").submit(function(e){
var fields = new Array("vault_user_first", "vault_user_last", "vault_country","vault_state","vault_city");
var i, l = fields.length;
var fieldname;
var reg_ex_text = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
fieldname = fields[i];
if (!document.forms["update_userdetails"][fieldname].value.match(reg_ex_text))
  {
    alert(document.forms["update_userdetails"][fieldname].value+' is not valid');
    e.preventDefault(e);
    break;
  }
 }
return true;
});
```